# Why would an MR16 LED light only work when power is cut?

Tags: led

I had just gotten a package of LED coloured light and all of them work except one. strangely as soon as I unplug it ,it flashes for a second. what does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: What kind of power supply does it use?

Comment: a 12volt MR16 plug and if this helps the plug prongs are a little slanted to the side

Answer (score 2):

Could be reversed polarity - and the power supply may put out an opposite voltage spike when shut off.

Comment: I had checked that and it is fine. thanks but i'm hoping i don't have to buy another one.